# can we give negative index as positional parameter in query approach spring data?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, crud-repository

I am using `@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id < ?-42", nativeQuery = true)` even though I am using -ve index as the positional parameters mymethod is fetching the details from the database correctly.Can we use -ve index or not because each time i change the index value i am getting the same output? or is it a bug? because i tried with 0 as positional parameters then i am getting the exception as out of bound exception.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 2
```

when i am using 0 as index.

```
(JVM running for 2.844)
Hibernate: SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id < ?-10
ProductDTO [productId=1, productName=potato, description=startc will be more good foe health, quantityAvailable=200]
ProductDTO [productId=2, productName=potato, description=startc will be more good foe health, quantityAvailable=200]
ProductDTO [productId=3, productName=potato, description=startc will be more good foe health, quantityAvailable=200]
```

this is my output when given -ve index

Comment: How is it that the productIds are different but the name is the same? Can you double check the data?

Comment: I'd is auto incremented value and rest of the columns I used same each time I run application 1 row is inserted with same details

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot use negative-numbered parameters in JPA.

Comment: But it is fetching the data when I give -ve index that data also I posted

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to say here. Nevertheless, I insist: negative indexes cannot be used. The parser for HQL does not even know how parse them. They are just not allowed. Sorry. End of story.